# Для чего нужен CMake?

Tags: cmake

Для чего мне может понадобится CMake?
Для быстрой компиляции?

Comment: В двух словах -- для полного контроля над процессом сборки. Пишете все руками и сами отвечаете за свои действия. Т.е. это инструмент профессионалов

Answer (score -16, accepted):

Утилиты make и Cmake это наследие Unix с тех времен, когда не было IDE, а в качестве терминала была пишущая машинка Консул(!). :-) В принципе, Unix-оиды до сих пор тащат эту методологию разработки и построения проектов, как наиболее общую. Иногда без нее не обойтись, но ее доля в реальной жизни снижается. Все работают на IDE и не заморачиваются с make и Cmake.

Вот еще для чего может понадобится Cmake, так это для распространения программ в виде Open Source. Если автор предоставляет Cmake для проекта, то пользователю проще на своей машине перестроить проект. И пользователю не надо в этом случае разбираться где там исходники, где хедеры, где библиотеки и прочее. Если же распространять с проектом не Cmake, а конфигурационный файл для IDE, то во-первых легко перестроить проект получится только с таким же IDE. А во-вторых IDE на машине пользователя должно стоять на том же диске и с теми же путями, что и на машине автора проекта.

---

> то этот пост все равно бы не объяснял - почему?

ТС и не спрашивал "почему". ТС спрашивал "зачем". ТС спрашивал зачем ему да и всем нам нужен CMake, если давно есть удобные IDE. Я попытался ответить зачем сейчас, в 2019 году, может быть нужен CMake. Ничего более убедительного, чем распространение Open Source проектов не вспомнилось.

Ответ же "почему" очевиден - потому что с IDE проще работать. При использовании IDE не надо вручную править конфигурацию CMake каждый раз при добавлении файла исходников в проект. И в IDE все в одном флаконе - и редактор, и отладчик, и компилятор и подсветка синтаксиса и форматирование исходников и подсветка ошибок и профилятор и еще куча всего. Всего этого нет в CMake и вообще всего этого нет в старой методологии разработки через командную строку. Именно поэтому CMake "загнан в темный угол". Именно поэтому 99% программистов работают только с IDE.

> Отсутствует этап конфигурации. На сегодняшний день мне неизвестно как
>   в С++ проекте студии указать, что ему требуется VasyanLib, да так
>   чтобы при попытке собрать проект, студия бы спросила меня о
>   местонахождении этой библиотеки, вместо того чтобы плеваться ошибками
>   сборки.

Не критично. 99% проектов обходятся статическим указанием на местоположение библиотек. Если будет критично, то эту функцию добавят в IDE.

> Сложно использовать сторонние утилиты в процессе сборки. Например, у
>   меня есть проект, который сначала собирает программу на Хаскелле,
>   запускает ее, а она производит код на С++, который уже превращается в
>   конечную программу. На CMake это заняло строчек 10, а на студии мне
>   неизвестно как это реализовать.

То же самое - не критично. 99% проектов обходятся без сторонних утилит в процессе сборки. Если будет критично, то эту функцию добавят в IDE. Предварительный запуск программы на Хаскелле для написания программы на С++ для последующей трансляции это такая ЭКЗОТИКА о которой и говорить не стоит. Так работают даже не 1% программистов, так работают 0.00001% программистов. Да вобщем-то и сейчас никто не обломится, запустив перед сборкой/после сборки отдельный батник со сторонними утилитами.

Все упомянутые "неудобства" пользования IDE не перевешивают "удобств" пользования IDE. А править вручную конфигурацию для Cmake это то еще удовольствие. Да еще при этом помнить все птичьи правила этого птичьего языка конфигураций.

В общем резюмируя - сборка Unix-style и вообще работа Unix-style времен батьки Денниса Ритчи это для олдскульного поколения, которое успело выучить язык конфигураций make и Cmake до того, как придумали IDE (спасибо за это кстати приснопамятной фирме Borland). Чем дальше, тем меньше остается таких динозавров что и к лучшему. Никто же сейчас не программирует в кодах. А когда-то были специалисты, которые помнили наизусть все коды(!) (даже не мнемоники ассемблера, а КОДЫ) всей системы команд PDP-11. :-)

> Он является генератором сценариев сборки, и таким образом, делает
>   проект переносимым между разными IDE и системами сборки,

Это все очень хорошо, но 99% проектов не нуждаются в переноске между разными IDE и системами сборки. Поэтому это свойство Cmake не востребовано в 99% случаев.

> а также позволяет более удобным способом, чем мышеклик, управлять
>   конфигурацией проекта.

Очень сомнительное утверждение.

> Основная беда проектных файлов того же вижака - это то, что они
>   отвратно версионируются, а для больших проектов это создает проблемы.

И каким образом использование Cmake помогает версионировать проекты? К тому же для версионирования сейчас используются всякие системы контроля версий типа того же git. Которые тоже ни разу не инструменты командной строки.

> так как противопоставлять CMake и IDE неправильно. Это система сборки, которая может использоваться и с IDE.

Может использоваться. А может и не использоваться. И 99% проектов не используют CMake. И 99% программистов не используют CMake. И чем дальше, тем эта цифра будет только расти. А вопрос был от человека, который счастливо живет под IDE и вдруг узнает что есть еще CMake. Естественно у него возникает вопрос - как же он жил до этого и не пользовался CMake и все у него работало? :-) А просто время CMake ушло и CMake остался только для старой гвардии, которая умирает но не сдается (С) Наполеон Бонапарт. :-)

---

С развитием хороших и разных IDE роль CMake и благословенной командной строки все время снижается. :-)

Довольно парадоксально выглядит, что ТС вполне удовлетворен ответом, а общественность продолжает негодовать и рассказывать, что собой представляет Cmake. Вопрос был не о том, что собой представляет Cmake, а вопрос был о том, зачем нужен Cmake, если есть IDE, которые умеют все, что умеет Cmake и таким образом IDE делает Cmake не нужным.

Автомобили заменили лошадей, а IDE вполне заменили Cmake. Это называется технический прогресс. Можно и сейчас ездить на телеге, но зачем? Можно и сейчас собирать проекты с помощью Cmake, но зачем?

Ну то есть понятно зачем. Действительно, существует 1% проектов, которые должны быть переносимы между разными IDE и платформами. Для таких проектов, возможно, применение Cmake и оправдано. Но это не мейнстим сейчас. Это глубоко нишевое применение.

Comment: `Все работают на IDE и не заморачиваются с make и Cmake. ` Очень сомнительное утверждение. Категорически не согласен с тем, что CMake назван "наследием".

Comment: @arrowd [сомнительное утверждение] Вот ТС искренно не понимает, зачем нужен CMake. То есть человек прожил жизнь пользуясь только IDE и не знал горя. И так же живут 99% программистов. Однако, Вы можете написать свой ответ, в котором обосновать свое видение ролей CMake и IDE на современном этапе развития технологий. Этим Вы обогатите "базу знаний" сайта stackoverflow. А также дадите всем участникам сайта повод подумать и согласиться (или не согласиться) с Вами.

Comment: Думаю, вас минусят не за то что вы "наехали" на Unix, и даже не за голословные заявления. Просто, даже если бы написанное вами было правдой, IDE бы загнали CMake в темный угол и "99% программистов" им бы не пользовалось, то этот пост все равно бы не объяснял - почему? Я постараюсь дать свой ответ.

Comment: Вы превратно понимаете порядок работы с CMAKE. Он является генератором сценариев сборки, и таким образом, делает проект переносимым между разными IDE и системами сборки, а также позволяет более удобным способом, чем мышеклик, управлять конфигурацией проекта.

Основная беда проектных файлов того же вижака - это то, что они отвратно версионируются, а для больших проектов это создает проблемы.

Comment: Я не Unix-оид, но все равно минуснул, так как противопоставлять CMake и IDE неправильно. Это система сборки, которая может использоваться и с IDE. Например, Visual Studio, начиная с 2017 версии, тоже поддерживает CMake (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/), помимо своей основной системы сборки - MSBuild. Серьезные проекты, например CoreCLR, уже используют эту возможность.

Comment: Большое удивление когда большой принятый ответ заминусовали. Вижу почему. CMake выполняет свою цель, и позволяет собрать проэкт или группу проэтов без участия человека в автоматическом режиме, а IDE предполагает наличие человека.

Comment: День добрый. Про само содержание ответа я даже говорить ничего не буду. Но рекомендую поправить ответ, чтоб он не отдавал таким пренебрежением по отношению к Unix-пользователям.

Comment: С каких пор гит стал неконсольным?

Comment: Насчет 99% вы явно погорячились, иначе счет был бы не +2/-9, а где-то +900/-9

Comment: @avp Если ориентироваться на счет, то получится, что 90% программистов сейчас пользуется CMake. А это явно не так. Так что Ваш критерий не релевантен.

Comment: С 99% и пренебрежительным отношением к линупсу вы явно категорически погорячились. Могу предположить, что когда-то у вас был негативный опыт и с тем и с другим. Не опускайте руки, попробуйте еще раз, там всё очень просто. Приходите сюда с вопросами - мы всегда поможем.

Comment: Зашёл сюда с RSDN (из "коллеги улыбнитесь"), но к сожалению, в русскоязычной версии маловато кармы чтобы голосовать :). Чтобы не быть голословным скажу, что CMake хоть и сильно закостыленный, но, тем не менее, индустриальный стандарт систем сборки для очень многих проектов. Тот же Qt6 будет использовать именно CMake для сборки. И очень многие фреймворки будут его использовать, просто чтобы компилироваться везде и всем.

Answer (score 29):

По просьбе [@pepsicoca1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192421/pepsicoca1) пишу развернутый пост.

---

**Компилятор**

Сначала был компилятор. Консольная программа, которой на вход даешь файл с кодом, а она тебе выдает файл-бинарник, который можно запустить. Для Unix-like это выглядело вот так:

```
gcc main.c
```

а для MSVC вот так:

```
cl.exe main.c
```

Однако, любой мало-мальски сложный проект содержит не один, а несколько (много!) файлов с исходным кодом. Можно было бы создать простенький скрипт, в котором было бы написано

```
gcc file1.c file2.c ... file123.c
```

Однако каждый раз, внося изменения лишь в один из файлов с кодом, вам нужно будет перекомпилировать программу, а эта команда будет пересобирать все 123 файла. Это медленно и неудобно. Требуется нечто, что будет детектировать измененные файлы и пересобирать только их.

---

**make**

Одним из таких решений является утилита `make`. Если вдаваться в подробности, то существует несколько диалектов `make`: на Linux используется т.н. GNU Make, на FreeBSD - BSD Make, а на винде - NMake.

`make` принимает на вход файл, описывающий **правила**. Каждое правило - это просто одна или несколько команд, которые производят какой-либо файл. Правила могут использовать файлы, получившиеся в результате выполнения других правил, и, таким образом, формируется **дерево зависимостей**. Все конечные результирующие файлы объединяются в правило `all`, поэтому команда `make all` позволяет "собрать" весь проект.

Я взял слово "собрать" в кавычки потому что, на самом деле, `make` не обязательно используется только с компиляторами. Мануал по `make` в заголовке гласит:

> make – maintain program dependencies

Т.е. `make` - это программа для управления зависимостями, причем не важно зависимостями чего от чего.

---

**Конфигурация проекта**

Беды на этом не кончились. Языки C и С++ устроены таким образом, что чтобы воспользоваться какой-либо сторонней библиотекой, вам необходимо указать компилятору путь до

1. Директории, содержащей **заголовочные файлы** библиотеки.
2. Директории, содержащей саму **библиотеку**.

Заголовочные файлы указываются флагом `-I` в Unix-подобных ОС и флагом `/I` в компиляторе Microsoft:

```
gcc -I/full/path/to/vasyanlib/include ...
cl.exe /I"C:\Program Files\VasyanLib\Include" ...
```

Аналогично, директории для библиотек указываются с помощью `-L` / `/LIBPATH`.

Но вот незадача - на разных компьютерах `VasyanLib` может быть установлена в разные директории! Это означает, что если вы захотите дать ваш код другому человеку, или просто самому скомпилировать ваш код на другой машине, то вам придется редактировать свой скриптик сборки (читай, команду вызова компилятора).

Это особенно неудобно, если ваш скрипт сборки находится под управлением системы контроля версий (`git`, `hg`, `svn` и т.д.), ведь вам придется либо каждый раз коммитить эти изменения, либо они будут "висеть" у вас незакомиченными.

И фиг бы с ними с библиотеками, но ведь иногда требуется отыскать сам компилятор, или какие-то файлы. А еще иногда требуется определить тип и версию ОС, поддерживаемые флаги компилятора, причем некоторые добавить, в зависимости от поддержки, и т.д.

Таким образом, помимо этапа **сборки** проекта появляется этап **конфигурации**. На этом этапе с помощью каких-либо скриптов или программ производятся необходимые проверки и поиски, а результат заносится в `Makefile` (ну, на сегодняшний день этот `Makefile` просто генерируется целиком) и/или оформляется в виде заголовочного файла с рядом директив `#define`, позволяющих в коде определить наличие того или иного файла или фичи.

---

**Системы сборки**

На данном этапе становится понятна роль программного обеспечения, называемого **системами сборки**. Они

1. Определяют структуру проекта, т.е. из каких "целей" он состоит. Например, проект может состоять из библиотеки, приложения, использующего эту библиотеку, и набора приложений-тестов.
2. Решают задачу **конфигурации** проекта.
3. Решают задачу **сборки** проекта.
4. Решают дополнительные задачи: **очистка** - удаление результатов сборки, **тестирование** - запуск тестов определенным образом, **упаковка** - создание релизных архив и инсталляторов, и т.д.

Пожалуй, первой системой сборки был Autotools. Сейчас их уже тьма-тьмущая и **CMake**, на мой взгляд, является наиболее универсальной из них. Остальные системы сборки либо зависимы от ОС, либо зависимы от языка программирования.

---

**CMake vs IDE**

Вот теперь, рассмотрев всю историю, можно разобрать и вопрос о том, является ли CMake и вообще системы сборки "наследием", и обошли ли их IDE.

Ответ - конечно нет. Подтверждение этому можно найти не только в том, что системы сборки постоянно и активно развиваются, но и в том что даже в Visual Studio, той самой IDE, которой не требовалась никакая система сборки, была добавлена поддержка CMake.

Пара слов о Visual Studio. Эта IDE имела свой формат проектов, и, по сути, свою собственную систему сборки. Проекты студии в функциональном смысле были эквивалентны `Makefile`ам или `CMakeLists.txt`ам. Неудобство пользованиями ими, на мой взгляд, заключается в следующем:

1. Отсутствует этап **конфигурации**. На сегодняшний день мне неизвестно как в С++ проекте студии указать, что ему требуется `VasyanLib`, да так чтобы при попытке собрать проект, студия бы спросила меня о местонахождении этой библиотеки, вместо того чтобы плеваться ошибками сборки.
2. Сложно использовать сторонние утилиты в процессе сборки. Например, у меня есть проект, который сначала собирает программу на Хаскелле, запускает ее, а она производит код на С++, который уже превращается в конечную программу. На CMake это заняло строчек 10, а на студии мне неизвестно как это реализовать.

---

**Философия**

На самом деле, файлы проектов IDE **не нужны**. Они не нужны по той причине, что файлы `CMakeLists.txt` - это уже **файлы проекта**. Причем они универсальны и не привязаны не только к ОС, но и к используемой IDE - в настоящее время CMake умеет генерить ,помимо Makefile, проекты Visual Studio и Eclipse.

Первая IDE, на мой взгляд, которая поняла эту глубокую мысль - [KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org/). В ней файлы проекта отсутствуют в принципе. Это не только классное решение с принципиальной точки зрения, но и имеет практическую ценность - например, KDevelop "видит" файлы проекта точно так же как сам CMake. В частности, если какой-то `#include` у вас подчеркивается красным, то это означает что вы накосячили в коде CMake. А в студии эта ошибка могла бы пройти мимо глаз, и проявиться только на другом компьютере с другой конфигурацией директорий.

Надеюсь, за такой развернутый пост мне простят беззастенчивую рекламу KDevelop. Но это и вправду замечательная IDE, на разработку которой я потратил немало времени.

Comment: то есть это просто продвинутая система сборки я так понимаю.

Comment: _"Сложно использовать сторонние утилиты в процессе сборки."_ - в VS довольно давно (а может и всегда) были шаги prebuild и postbuild. Так что хаскельный генератор кода просто прописывается в prebuild и будет запускаться когда надо. Вроде там даже больше триггеров есть.

Comment: @Rundogie Rundogie Не более продвинутая, а более ранняя. И, как следствие, менее удобная.

Comment: @Qwertiy [были шаги prebuild и postbuild] Так давно все сделано! Впрочем это логично, сделать это в IDE ничего не стоит. Вот насколько это никому не нужно, что я даже и не обращал внимания что там есть шаги prebuild и postbuild. :-)

Comment: @Rundogie Rundogie [почему мы программисты должны возиться] А никто и не возится. со всякими сборками. Даже Юниксоиды используют свои юниксоидные IDE (типа упомянутого  KDevelop) которые суть надстройки над их любимым Cmake. И эти юниксоидные IDE позволяют Юниксоидам править конфиги к Cmake просто выставляя галочки (какой позор для ревнителей древлего юниксового благочестия :-)) как в Visual Studio. Разница в том, что конфиги VS бинарные и закрытые. А конфиги KDevelop текстовые и открытые. С текстовыми конфигами труднее работать программе, но удобнее работать людям. А с бинарными наоборот.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie Потратили вы два дня потому что у вас опыта мало. Ну и отчасти потому что там система сборки какая-то неведомая - premake. Еще раз, если бы 100% разработчиков пользовали бы студию, то нужды в CMake бы не было. Но объективная реальность такова, что в ней куча IDE и у всех свои форматы проектов. Нужен какой-то общий знаменатель и этот знаменатель - CMake.

Comment: В `Building.md` сказано подключить все файлы, включая `.cpp`. Просто прописав пути до инклудов вы получите ошибки на этапе компоновки.

Comment: " IDE, на разработку которой я потратил немало времени" - так это вы разработчик KDevelop?

Answer (score 10):

CMake (равно как и make, qmake, gmake, consul итд) нужен для описания правил сборки проекта. То есть он призван отвечать на вопросы

- Где у проекта лежат исходники?
- Какое имя бинарника проекта?
- Какие имена библиотек проекта?
- Какие внешние библиотеки проект использует и где они находятся?
- Сборка в дебаг или релиз?
- Какие действия выполнить перед сборкой? А после?
- Что нибудь ещё...

К тому же CMake это не просто декларативное описание, это вполне себе язык, на котором пишется код, который собирает проект, при этом у CMake уже готово множество методов для автоматизации поиска библиотек, текущей архитектуры и так далее.

При этом файл CMake намного более читабелен и понятен, чем, например, solution в visual studio.

Я, например, в одном из своих pet-проектов про arduino одним CMake-файлом собираю демона для linux, прошивку для arduino и заливаю эту прошивку в arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Для организации `C/C++` проекта. Достаточно зайти на официальный сайт https://cmake.org/.

> CMake is an open-source, cross-platform family of tools designed to
>   build, test and package software. CMake is used to control the
>   software compilation process using simple platform and compiler
>   independent configuration files, and generate native makefiles and
>   workspaces that can be used in the compiler environment of your
>   choice.

Comment: То есть утилита бесполезная если я уже знаю какой компилятор я буду использовать?

Comment: @RundogieRundogie Я в Сях не шарю и заглянул сюда лишь из любопытства, но насколько мне известно, билдер и компилятор - это совершенно разные вещи. Компилятор превращает в исполняемый код программу, которая собирается билдером из файлов проекта.

Comment: Да, но то есть в IDE у меня получается уже есть и билдер и компилятор.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie зависит от IDE. В Visual Studio - да. Но есть IDE, которые используют компилятор и систему сборки, поставленные отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания программ под микроконтроллеры альтернативе утилитам make и cmake иногда просто нету. IDE от производителя вставляют в код большой объем не используемого кода и удалить его из программы средствами IDE не возможно. Приходится собирать проект без IDE.

Comment: не надо путать make и CMake. Если грубо, make исполняет MAKEFILE,  CMake - создаёт MAKEFILE, чтобы make мог его выполнить. CMake is an open-source, cross-platform family of tools designed to build, test and package software. И про IDE: приведите пример.